Unity Nav Mesh Agent Local Avoidance
I'm trying to make a RTS game with Unity, trying out the nav mesh agent. Basically when an agent calculates it's path, it does not consider other agents so if they want to reach the same destination they'll push each other around for that spot. What I'm trying to do is add a nav mesh obstacle, disable agent and enable obstacle when unit is not moving, disable obstacle and enable agent when it needs to move. It works ok but when the units start to move again, it jiggles for some reason. I thought it's because the obstacle was still active when agent so it is pushed by the obstacle, but I made sure the obstacle is disabled first.
